# print output from Java file to pysimplegui screen

Tags: java, pysimplegui

Here is my main.py

```
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE
import PySimpleGUI as sg



def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java(java_file):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class, 'hello']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
    input=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=PIPE)
    print(proc.stdout.read())


logwindow = sg.Multiline(size=(70, 20), font=('Courier', 10))
print = logwindow.print
layout = [[logwindow]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
    compile_java("hello_world.java")
    execute_java("HelloWorld")
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

And here is my java file

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
         System.out.println(args[0]);
        
    }
}
```

I want the print statement within the java file to print to my GUI screen and not the console. But only the print statement in the python file prints to the GUI screen